# Installing Drupal with Drush make and install profile and using a bash script - how to answer yes/no?

Tags: bash, drupal, drush

I have a bash script and when I run it, I'm asked the question:

> "You are about to create a sites/default/files directory and create a
>   sites/default/settings.php file and DROP all tables in your 'geo_test'
>   database. Do you want to continue? (y/n)"

How do I answer 'y' automatically?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
#sudo rm -rf geoslate
drush make distro.make geoslate --working-copy --no-gitinfofile
cd geoslate
drush si geoslate --db-url='mysql://root:root@localhost/geo_test' --site-name=Geoslate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `-y` option should to it:

```
drush si geoslate -y --db-url='mysql://root:root@localhost/geo_test' --site-name=Geoslate
```